# loop each element and print word2vec vectors based on the element

Tags: python, printing, word2vec

I would like to print each vector of a word by using gensim word2vec.

Here is my code:

```
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
a = [["man", "eater", "king"]]
model = Word2Vec(a, size =100, window=1, min_count=1)
model.build_vocab(a, update=True)
model.train(a, total_examples=1, epochs=1)

""" I know that I could use:
    for x in a:
        print(model.wv[x])

    This is not I intended because I wanted to know whether is there a possibility
    to loop each element in a list and return it into the model.wv[element] by printing 
    every each element by using only 1 line of code"""

#For example my intended way
print(model.wv[x for x in a])
```

However, this is list comprehensive method and it wont work. I also tried

```
print(model.wv[lambda x:x, a])
```

But still dont work. Could anyone please tell me how can I print every each word vector 
without using the for loop way? I just want it to be 1 line for the print part.
If it is still not clear, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a list comprehension here, but not in the format you described:

`[print(model.wv[x]) for x in a]`

Comment: Thank you so much. I didnt realize that I could use it this way. This is really another learning to me.